# Values of CSV headers being null, despite data being in the CSV file headers

Tags: powershell, ms-office

I am working on a script that is going to remove all disabled Users from certain Dls in the company and the licenses that may be attached to the user accounts.

So far when I run it, it gives me an error stating that the parameters in the script are null, but there are clear headers within the exported CSV file. The script is:

```
Get-MsolUser -EnabledFilter DisabledOnly| select UserPrincipalName, isLicensed |Export-Csv -path "file\path\test" 

$Remove = Import-Csv "file\path\test"| Out-String 

Foreach($users in $Remove) {

    Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity CC@company.com -Member $users.UserPrincipalName -Confirm:$false

    Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity Sales -User $users.UserPrincipalName -AccessRights FullAcces -InheritanceType All -Confirm:$false

    Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity Everyone -Member $users.UserPrincipalName -Confirm:$false

        if($user.isLicensed -eq "true") {
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $users.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "reseller-account:DESKLESSPACK"

        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $users.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "reseller-account:O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM"

        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $users.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "reseller-account:EXCHANGEDESKLESS"

        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $users.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "reseller-account:O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS"
        }
}

Remove-Item –path "file\path\test" –recurse
```

They have the two headers `UserPrincipalName` and `isLicensed`, but the error I get is that the `member` and `user` are both null.

Please let me know what you think

Comment: `| Out-String` Why?

Comment: I thought that was the correct action to do when working with CSV files. From my understanding is the way to help it differentiate from it being an object and a string

Comment: Incorrect.  That takes your object as it would print to the console and turns it into a string.  So now what you have in `$Remove` is actually a `string` object that represents the table that your object would look like.

Comment: OK I will remove the `| Out-String` and see if that will fix it

Comment: Well, thank you for that. That was why, You answered the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Import-Csv`, it converts that information to a `pscustomobject` with the headers as the keys to access your information.  When you use `| Out-String` it converts that object into a `string` with the formatting based on whatever the `ps1xml` file says about the `pscustomobject` type.

CSV:

```
"a","b","c"
"1","2","3"
```

Code:

```
(Import-Csv -Path .\example.csv).GetType().FullName
# => System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

(Import-Csv -Path .\example.csv | Out-String).GetType().FullName
# => System.String
```

The error you ran into was that the `string` type doesn't have the members you were trying to access.